# Windows Azure Mobile app Code First Migratoin Issue

Tags: azure

i built an Mobile App on Windows Azure and Visual Studio Community 2015. All Works fine, the local version works like charm. But when i deploy to Azure Mobile App the nightmare began.

After publishing with the option "Execute Code First...." the Site Appears, that an object allready exist in the database with the same Name.

Failure:
[SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'users' in the database.]

users is the First create table statement in initial script.

in the Global.asax i changed the Migrator Init to:

```
        //Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
        migrator.Update();
```

i also delete the whole Mobile App in Azure and build one new from scratch, same Problem. it crashes always on the initial script in the Migrations Folder. Local all Work perfect...

i´m serching for a solution since days...i hope anybody can give me an hint...

Reagrds,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hint.
The Migrationname in the database was not the same as in the Configuration.
Deleted all Tables and republish.

I think this is not a normal bug it`s a brain bug :-)

Regards,
Marcus